# Unable to deserialize the JSON Data

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net, webapi

I'm currently using an API to grab some player information, which looks like this in raw data form:

```
{
  "response": {
    "players": [
      {
        "steamid": "76561198166559342",
        "communityvisibilitystate": 1,
        "profilestate": 1,
        "personaname": "Stack Overflow",
        "commentpermission": 2,
        "profileurl": "https://steamcommunity.com/id/stackoverflow/",
        "avatar": "https://avatars.akamai.steamstatic.com/8a2e52a3eaefed0296459fa811aasdasd1ce29374.jpg",
        "avatarmedium": "https://avatars.akamai.steamstatic.com/8a2e52a3eaefed0296459fa81asdas1ce29374_medium.jpg",
        "avatarfull": "https://avatars.akamai.steamstatic.com/8a2e52a3eaefed0296459fa811a61212312e29374_full.jpg",
        "avatarhash": "8a2e52a3eaefed02asdasd",
        "personastate": 0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to just grab the "personaname" and "avatar" values from my data, which have been quite unsuccessful, so I've tried to objectify the JSON before getting it, which still isn't working:

```cs
Models.SteamUser persona;

String httpres;
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    string steamurl = "MY HIDDEN URL HERE" + s64;
    var steamapi = new Uri(steamurl);
    var result = client.GetAsync(steamapi).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    var json = result.ToString();
    httpres = json;
    var jUser = JObject.Parse(json);
    var userData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.SteamUser>(jUser["players"]).ToString(); ;
    persona = userData;
}
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: 1. To get the players, `jUser["response"]["players"]` and deserialize as `List<Models.SteamUser>`. `jUser["response"]["players"]` is an array. To get first item, you need `.First()` or `.FirstOrDefault()`. 2. You are assigned `userData` which is a `string` to persona (`Models.SteamUser`). Doubt that it will not be working as both are different types.

Comment: 3. It's not suggested to perform `Task.Result` as it makes to call the thread synchronously and may lead to a deadlock. Reading: [What happens while waiting on a Task's Result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12484112/what-happens-while-waiting-on-a-tasks-result)

Answer (score 1):

1. To get `players` from the JSON response, you need `jObj["response"]["players"]` instead of `jObj["players"]`.
2. You have to deserialize as `List<Models.SteamUser>` but not `Models.SteamUser` as it is an array. Then with `IEnumerable.FirstOrDefault()` to get the first item of the array.
3. From the existing code, the `userData` is `string` type while `persona` is `List<Models.SteamUser>` type. You can't assign `userData` to `persona`.
4. Not suggested using `Task.Result` as it performs the operation synchronously and waits for the operation to be completed. Hence, it may lead to a deadlock. Instead, works with **`async`/`await`**. Source: [What happens while waiting on a Task's Result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12484112/what-happens-while-waiting-on-a-tasks-result)

Your code should be looked as below:

```
Models.SteamUser persona = null;

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    string steamurl = "MY HIDDEN URL HERE" + s64;
    var steamapi = new Uri(steamurl);
    var response = await client.GetAsync(steamapi);

    var jsonResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var jObj = JObject.Parse(jsonResult);
    var players = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Models.SteamUser>>(jObj["response"]["players"].ToString());

    // Or
    // var players = (jObj["response"]["players"] as JArray).ToObject<List<Models.SteamUser>>();
    
    persona = players.FirstOrDefault();
}
```